# The best way to register process start time?

Tags: c#, process, timer

I am writing a program that must register time of starting a process such as *notepad*.
I thought that it is good to create a Timer that checks all of processes every second. But I think that it will slow down the user's computer. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Yes, constant polling is the wrong solution for many reasons, not the least of which is performance degradation. You're looking for a hook. But you can't write the hook DLL in C#; you'll need to use either C or C++ for that.

Comment: What is your actual goal? It is difficult to give you an answer that does solve your problem. Do you want to monitor any process start or only the start of a specific process? Do you need to get the runtime of the monitored processes exactly or are you only interested in processes which do run longer e.g. 10 minutes? Depending on your answer it may turn out that polling is a "good enough" tradeoff. There are exact ways to do it but these are significantly more complex.

Comment: Sorry, **English is difficult for me**. I want to meter time of running a process and register it in a txt file. But I don't want to check it every second.

Comment: I could offer German as alternative ;-). Can you describe your goal? Is it learning or did you run into issues with your current approach?

Comment: What is the diffrence? I want to know how long user plays game with computer or how long powerpoint is open?

Comment: In that case it is ok to poll and check lets say every 10 minutes all processes and check how long they are running with the StartTime property. This will not make your computer noticeable slower.

Comment: To think, this is only way left.

Comment: @MoctavaFarzán: I've updated my answer. There is a more resource friendly version of process creation detection using WMI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initially determine for all running processes the creation time. Then
use WMI to register for process creation events.

See the code below for a small example on how to use WMI for process creation events:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  using (ManagementEventWatcher eventWatcher =
            new ManagementEventWatcher(@"SELECT * FROM 
   __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'"))
  {
    // Subscribe for process creation notification.
    eventWatcher.EventArrived += ProcessStarted_EventArrived; 
    eventWatcher.Start();
    Console.In.ReadLine();
    eventWatcher.EventArrived -= ProcessStarted_EventArrived;
    eventWatcher.Stop();
  }
}


static void ProcessStarted_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
  ManagementBaseObject obj = e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"] as ManagementBaseObject;

  // The Win32_Process class also contains a CreationDate property.
  Console.Out.WriteLine("ProcessName: {0} " + obj.Properties["Name"].Value);
}
```

**BEGIN EDIT:**

I've further investigated process creation detection with WMI and there is a (more) resouces friendly solution (but needs administrative privileges) using the `Win32_ProcessStartTrace` class (please see [TECHNET](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692849.aspx) for further information):

```
using (ManagementEventWatcher eventWatcher =
          new ManagementEventWatcher(@"SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace"))
{
  // Subscribe for process creation notification.
  eventWatcher.EventArrived += ProcessStarted_EventArrived;
  eventWatcher.Start();
  Console.Out.WriteLine("started");
  Console.In.ReadLine();
  eventWatcher.EventArrived -= ProcessStarted_EventArrived;
  eventWatcher.Stop();
}

static void ProcessStarted_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{               
  Console.Out.WriteLine("ProcessName: {0} " 
          + e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessName"].Value);     
}
```

In this solution you do not have to set an polling interval.

**END EDIT**

**BEGIN EDIT 2:**

You could use the `Win32_ProcessStopTrace` class to monitor process stop events. To combine both process start and process stop events use the `Win32_ProcessTrace` class. In the event handler use the `ClassPath` proberty to distinguish between start/stop events:

```
using (ManagementEventWatcher eventWatcher =
       new ManagementEventWatcher(@"SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessTrace"))
{          
  eventWatcher.EventArrived += Process_EventArrived;
  eventWatcher.Start();
  Console.Out.WriteLine("started");
  Console.In.ReadLine();
  eventWatcher.EventArrived -= Process_EventArrived;
  eventWatcher.Stop();
}

static void Process_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
  Console.Out.WriteLine(e.NewEvent.ClassPath); // Use class path to distinguish
                                               // between start/stop process events.
  Console.Out.WriteLine("ProcessName: {0} " 
      + e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessName"].Value);     
}
```

**END EDIT 2**

Comment: -1 first WMI does internally pool. Second you do not need to even use WMI. The OS does record the start time of every process already. All you need to do is to read it. See my answer below.

Comment: Thank's. Is there a way to check closing processes too?

Comment: @MoctavaFarzán: Yes, there is also a __InstanceDeletionEvent event. But if you plan to use both __InstanceDeletionEvent  and __InstanceCreationEvent you should subscribe for the __InstanceOperationEvent and then check in your callback which event was fired by evaluating the e.NewEvent.ClassPath.ClassName property.

Comment: I will test it tomorrow. I could not test it today.

Comment: @MoctavaFarzán: You could also set the polling interval in the first solution to a greater value.

Comment: +1 The second approach seems to be a real callback. This WMI call does not poll. As far as I have read it is basically a wrapper around ETW to capture process started events logged by the kernel. Any other option is much more complex like writing your own kernel driver to capture the necessary events like procmon does it. http://www.decuslib.com/decus/vmslt00a/nt/filemon.htm

Comment: Yes, @Hans. The second code is exactly what I wanted. Please help me about closing processes too. I did not understand **THECHNET** because that was in vb 6.

Comment: @MoctavaFarzán: Sorry for the late response. I've updated my answer to show how to trap process stop events.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to monitor anything at all. All you need to do is to enumerate your processes and fetch from the Process Instances [StartTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.starttime.aspx).

Comment: But you certainly have to use a timer or something like that? Enumerating the processes once is not enough. So, I do not understand why you down voted my answer?

Comment: There are ways to achieve it without a timer. The main issue with your answer is that with "__InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 1" you do poll every second. If a process does start and stop within that time you will never get any notification at all. If you know which process you want to check you can get a callback from the OS when you use Image File Execution Options. But first Farzan should state how he does get the processes in question and which are interesting for him. There are many ways to achieve this.

Comment: Yes, I aggree. There are many solutions such as Image File Execution Options, Hooks, polling using a timer, using WMI or using a driver. So, I really did not understand your down vote.

Comment: But I think that it is better than using Timer, @AloisKraus.

Comment: Have you actually tried to run your code? If you set __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 0.1 you and then you sort the CPU consumption of your processes you will find WmiPrvSE.exe consuming over 30% CPU. You are right that in your process nearly nothing happens but in reality you did offload the polling only to another process. WMIs architecture with regards to its event model is inherently flawed because there is no other way than to poll. It gives you the illusion to register to events which are not based on polling but the reality is that WMI will poll.

Comment: Yes, You are right. What I must to do? **StartTime** isn't a good option for me because I don't know when the process will run.